# jquery color picker error

Tags: jquery, color-picker

I am trying to implement the jquery colorpicker(last one) from [eyecon.ro/colorpicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/) but whenever I click on the actual colorpicker nothing appears jquery throw this error message

```
$("#colorSelector").ColorPicker is not a function
 onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
```

Here is my code

js file

```
// Colorpicker
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
color: '#0000ff',
onShow: function (colpkr) {
    $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
    return false;
},
onHide: function (colpkr) {
    $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
    return false;
},
onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
    $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
}
});
```

HTML file

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorpicker.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css" />
    <title>ColorPicker - jQuery plugin</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/colorpicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/eye.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/layout.js?ver=1.0.2"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>
         <div id="colorSelector"><div style="background-color: #0000ff"></div></div>
      </p>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have all the files included and css colorpicker is just not working. Any suggestions on how I can get rid of that error?

Comment: Did you include the plug-in before or after the jQuery library? Make sure you include it *after*.

Comment: @cory after the jquery library and I have updated code above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/colorpicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                            var borderColor;

            $('#tbcontentBorder').ColorPicker({
                onSubmit : function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
                    $(el).val('#' + hex);
                    $(el).ColorPickerHide();
                    borderColor = $('#tbcontentBorder').val();
                    $('#news').css('border-color', borderColor);
                },
                onBeforeShow : function() {
                    $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
                }
            }).bind('keyup', function() {

                $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);

            });
        });

    </script>
```

html

```
<div class="textBoxHolder">
        <label >Select Color</label>
        <input type="color" id="tbcontentBorder"  />
    </div>
```

its working fine for me

Comment: There was a bug in my terminal so I had to restart my server and everything was working from there. I also had `$.noConflict();` to my js file

Comment: @coletrain: Make sure you're using `noConflict()` mode correctly. That function returns a variable, and it's that variable you should be using instead of `$` (e.g. `var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); $j('#selector').something();`).

Answer (score 2):

Did you add a textbox control, i.e. `<input type="text"/>`? In your html
give an ID to the text box which will select the color.